# Folium-ChoropletMap issues with key_on: does not overlay the choroplet map

Tags: geojson, geopandas, folium, choropleth

I have a strange issue with the following piece of code:

```
    m10=folium.Map(location=[41.9027835,12.4963655],tiles='openstreetmap',zoom_start=5) 
    df.reset_index(inplace = True)  
    folium.Choropleth(
    geo_data = df.to_json(),
    data = df,
    columns=['TERRITORIO', var],
    key_on='feature.properties.TERRITORIO',
    fill_color='YlGnBu', 
    fill_opacity=0.6, 
    line_opacity=1,
    nan_fill_color='black',
    legend_name= get_title_(file_name),
    smooth_factor=0).add_to(m10)

    folium.features.GeoJson(df,
                        name='Labels',
                        style_function=lambda x: {'color':'transparent','fillColor':'transparent','weight':0},
                        tooltip=folium.features.GeoJsonTooltip(fields=[var],
                                                                aliases = [indicator], 
                                                                labels=True,
                                                                sticky=False
                                                                            )
                       ).add_to(m10)
```

I use the same piece of code on two different  geodataframes. With the first (smaller) dataframe I have no issues.
[image]

However, when I try to do the same with the other one I do not see the choroplet map layer.
[image]

This is the first dataset (after the reset of the index):

```
    TERRITORIO  ...                                           geometry
0         Nord  ...  MULTIPOLYGON (((9.85086 44.02340, 9.85063 44.0...
1       Centro  ...  MULTIPOLYGON (((10.31417 42.35043, 10.31424 42...
2  Mezzogiorno  ...  MULTIPOLYGON (((8.41112 38.86296, 8.41127 38.8...
```

This is the second dataset (after the reset of the index)

```
       TERRITORIO  ...                                           geometry
0         Abruzzo  ...  MULTIPOLYGON (((930273.425 4714737.743, 930147...
1      Basilicata  ...  MULTIPOLYGON (((1073851.435 4445828.604, 10738...
2        Calabria  ...  MULTIPOLYGON (((1083350.847 4416684.239, 10833...
3        Campania  ...  MULTIPOLYGON (((1037266.901 4449456.848, 10372...
4  Emilia-Romagna  ...  MULTIPOLYGON (((618335.211 4893983.160, 618329...
```

These are insted the json files:
first:

```
{"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [{"id": "0", "type": "Feature", "properties": {"INDICATORE": "Densit\\u00e0 di verde storico", "NOTE": null, "Shape_Area": 57926800546.7, "Shape_Leng": 2670893.51269, "TERRITORIO": "Nord", "UNITA_MISURA": "per 100 m2", "V_2004": null, "V_2005": null, "V_2006": null, "V_2007": null, "V_2008": null, "V_2009": null, "V_2010": null, "V_2011": 2.4, "V_2012": 2.4, "V_2013": 2.4, "V_2014": 2.4, "V_2015": 2.4, "V_2016": 2.4, "V_2017": 2.4, "V_2018": 2.4, "V_2019": null, "index": 0}, "geometry": {"type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": ...
```

second:

```
{"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [{"id": "0", "type": "Feature", "properties": {"INDICATORE": "Densit\\u00e0 e rilevanza del patrimonio museale", "NOTE": null, "Shape_Area": 10831496151.0, "Shape_Leng": 664538.009079, "TERRITORIO": "Abruzzo", "UNITA_MISURA": "per 100 km2", "V_2004": null, "V_2005": null, "V_2006": null, "V_2007": null, "V_2008": null, "V_2009": null, "V_2010": null, "V_2011": null, "V_2012": null, "V_2013": null, "V_2014": null, "V_2015": 0.22, "V_2016": null, "V_2017": 0.13, "V_2018": 0.11, "V_2019": null}, "geometry": {"type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates":...
```

I really do not understand why one works and the other does not.

Do you have any suggestion?

Thank you in advance for your time!

Comment: one obvious thing - the two geodataframes are using different CRS

Answer (score 1):

- I can't find any geometry for Nord, Centro, Mezzogiorno Italy, so have sythesized by dissolving regions geometry
- have setup functions and variables used by your code to make this a MWE
- can switch between geometries by `# regions==False, north/central/south==True if True:` **both** generate appropriate **folium** maps
- it's clear in your question that your two sets of geometry are using different CRS.  First data set looks like EPSG:4326 (hence works).  Second looks like a UTM CRS (points in meters not degrees) that would need to be projected to EPSG:4326

```
import folium
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np

# make SO code runnable, get some geometry and set columns / variables used by code
df = gpd.read_file("https://github.com/openpolis/geojson-italy/raw/master/geojson/limits_IT_regions.geojson").sort_values("reg_name")
df["var"] = np.random.randint(1,10,len(df))
df["TERRITORIO"] = df["reg_istat_code_num"]
df["NCM"] = np.where(df["reg_istat_code_num"]<9,"Nord", np.where(df["reg_istat_code_num"]<15,"Centro", "Mezzogiorno"))
var = "var"
file_name="regions"
indicator = "some number"
def get_title_(file_name):
    return file_name

# regions==False, north/central/south==True
if True:
    df = df.dissolve("NCM")
    file_name = "ncm"
    
# unchanged code
m10 = folium.Map(location=[41.9027835, 12.4963655], tiles="openstreetmap", zoom_start=5)
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
folium.Choropleth(
    geo_data=df.to_json(),
    data=df,
    columns=["TERRITORIO", var],
    key_on="feature.properties.TERRITORIO",
    fill_color="YlGnBu",
    fill_opacity=0.6,
    line_opacity=1,
    nan_fill_color="black",
    legend_name=get_title_(file_name),
    smooth_factor=0,
).add_to(m10)

folium.features.GeoJson(
    df,
    name="Labels",
    style_function=lambda x: {
        "color": "transparent",
        "fillColor": "transparent",
        "weight": 0,
    },
    tooltip=folium.features.GeoJsonTooltip(
        fields=[var], aliases=[indicator], labels=True, sticky=False
    ),
).add_to(m10)

m10
```

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the crs I was able to overcome the above issiue.

```
    # Create the folium map 
m10=folium.Map(location=[41.9027835,12.4963655],tiles='openstreetmap',zoom_start=5)

# Data

df.to_crs(crs = 4326, inplace = True)
```

df.reset_index(inplace = True)

```
folium.Choropleth(
geo_data = df.to_json(),
data = df,
columns=['TERRITORIO', var],
key_on='feature.properties.TERRITORIO',
fill_color='YlGnBu', 
fill_opacity=0.6, 
line_opacity=1,
nan_fill_color='black',
legend_name= get_title_(file_name),
smooth_factor=0).add_to(m10)
```